# Hamburger Menu Links not working in Nextjs

Tags: css, next.js

Hey im not sure what im doing wrong. My menu links work but in mobile view when i open hamburger menu the links stop working, I currently have my menu in a layout component should I make hamburger menu its own component?

here is what i Have

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const openMenu = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);
 return (
  <>
  <header className={styles.header}>
    <nav className={styles.navbar}>
      <Link href="/">
        <a><Image src={logo} height={50} width={265} /></a>
      </Link>
      <ul className={isOpen === false ? styles.navmenu : styles.navmenu + " " + styles.active}>

        <li className={styles.navitem}>
          <Link href="/">
            <a className={isOpen === false ? styles.navlink : styles.navlink + " " + styles.active}onClick={openMenu}>Shop</a>
          </Link>
        </li>

        <li className={styles.navitem}>
          <Link href="/team">
            <a className={isOpen === false ? styles.navlink : styles.navlink + " " + styles.active} onClick={openMenu}>
              Team
            </a>
          </Link>
        </li>

        <li className={styles.navitem}>
          <Link href="/contact">
            <a className={isOpen === false ? styles.navlink : styles.navlink + " " + styles.active} onClick={openMenu}>
              Contact
            </a>
          </Link>
        </li>

        <li className={styles.navitem}>
            {publicKey ? renderConnectedContainer() : renderNotConnectedContainer() }
        </li>
      </ul>

      <button className={isOpen === false ? styles.hamburger : styles.hamburger + " " + styles.active} onClick={openMenu}>
        <span className={styles.bar}></span>
        <span className={styles.bar}></span>
        <span className={styles.bar}></span>
      </button>
    </nav>
  </header>
```